# Delete Column if empty except header

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to go through each column (all have headers) and if the entire column except the header is empty, delete the column. Here is what I have.

```
 Sub hideEmptyColumns()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim lngLastColumn As Long
 lngLastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
 For i = 1 To lngLastColumn
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i)) = 0 Then
        Columns(i).Delete
    End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

But I can't figure out how to offset the column by just one row (top row for headers).

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for by getting the last used row in each column and if the last row = 1 then delete.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lnglastcolumn As Long
    Dim delrng As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lnglastcolumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For i = 1 To lnglastcolumn
            If .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
                If delrng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delrng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set delrng = Union(delrng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    delrng.Delete
```

I unionized the delete range so there's no need to mess with the iterator to handle columns shifting, also it is faster.